# Angular - Remove html element without a class

Tags: html, angular

I have a component where you can pass a class into the html,

```
<my-component myClass="hello-class"></my-component>
```

And in the component html,

```
<div class="{{myClass}}"> Div with the class</div>
<div>A div without the class</div>
```

But there are cases where you might not pass a class into `myClass`.

In a scenario like that, I want to remove the div that needed the class input from the user,

`<my-component></my-component>` (no class passed in)

Only shows the div that is not does not need the class.

```
<div>A div without the class</div>
```

Is there a condition I can pass into the html to do this,

Ex:

```
<div *ngIf="myClass-is-not-empty" class="{{myClass}}"> Div with the class</div>
<div>A div without the class</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="myClass" class="{{myClass}}"> Div with the class</div>
<div>A div without the class</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="!!myClass" class={{myClass}}">
```